# When $x^n - (x+a)^{n-k} (x+b)^k$ is irreducible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Fix a nonzero integer $a$ and a positive integer $k$. I'm looking for some criterion to establish for which nonzero integers $b$ and $n \geq 2$ the polynomial
$$f(x) := x^n - (x+a)^{n-k} (x+b)^k$$
is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I think it is irreducible at least for all sufficiently large $n$, but I failed to prove it.

EDIT: The question is more complicated than I expected. So I specify that I'd be happy just to prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ **for any** nonzero integer $b \neq -a$. Peter Mueller's comments below show that these $n$ must be relatively prime with $k$, so maybe a good guess is to consider $n$ prime.

Thank you in advance for any idea.

Comment: In the special case where $a=b$, the roots of your polynomial are the $\zeta a/(1-\zeta)$ where $\zeta\neq 1$ is a $n$-th root of $1$. So the polynomial is irreducible if and only if $n$ is prime. In particular, $n$ large is not sufficient.

Comment: Whenever $k$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, your polynomial is reducible.

Comment: @Peter: not quite "whenever": $n=2$, $k=1$, $a=1$, $b=-1$.

Comment: However, for each $(a,k)$ there are infinitely many $(n,b)$ such that your polynomial is irreducible. Take $n$ prime, $p$ a prime not dividing $a$ and having multiplicative order $n-1$ modulo $n$, and $b$ congruent to $a$ modulo $p$. Then the polynomial is irreducible modulo $p$.

Comment: One way to approach this for arbitrary $n,b$ is to pick a prime $p$ dividing $a$ (assuming $a\ne\pm1$), and compute the inertia group of a prime over $p$ in the splitting field of $f(x)$.  This might work out nicely because $f(x)$ reduces mod $p$ to $x^{n-k}(x^k-(x+b)^k)$, whose factorization is under control, and then hopefully Hensel's lemma yields the factorization over $\mathbf{Z}_p$.  The hope is that these inertia groups will generate a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, implying irreducibility.

Comment: If $n=2m,k=m$ and $b=-a$ then the polynomial is $f(x)= x^{2m}-(x^2-a^2)^m$ and is reducible.

Comment: @Aakumadula: More generally (see my "not quite correct" comment from above) if $n=ur$ and $k=vr$, then $x^u-(x+a)^{u-v}(x+b)^v$ is a divisor of $f(x)$; and if $r>1$, this is a proper divisor unless $x^u-(x+a)^{u-v}(x+b)^v$ is a constant, which happens only if $u=2$, $v=1$, $a=-b$, so $f(x)=x^{2r}-(x^2-a^2)^r$. But this latter polynomial is irreducible if and only if $r$ is a prime.

Comment: @Aurel (second comment): You may even fix $n$: If $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, and $t$ is a transcendental, then it follows easily (e.g. from Capelli's Theorem) that $x^n-(x+a)^{n-k}(x+t)^k$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(t)$. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible for infinitely many integers $b$ by Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem.

Comment: @PeterMueller: thanks, I was wondering when $f$ was irreducible as a multivariate polynomial, but I do not know multivariate polynomials very well. What is this Capelli's theorem ?

Comment: @Aurel: Capelli's Theorem says that $x^n-c$ is irreducible over a field $K$, if the following holds: $c$ is not a $p$-th power in $K$ for each prime divisor $p$ of $n$, and if $4$ divides $n$, then $-4c$ is not a $4$-th power as well. In your case with a variable $t$ instead of $b$, set $y=x+t$ and consider $y^k-x^n/(x+a)^{n-k}$ over $\mathbb Q(x)$.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I edited the question to make the problem a little less general. @MichaelZieve: your suggestion seems hopeful. However I don't know much on inertia group and using Hensel's lemma to prove irreducibility. I will try to investigate and I would be happy if you could explain much in details your idea.

Comment: @Marc: the basic idea is that, if $K$ is a field containing $\mathbf{Q}$, then the Galois group of $f(x)$ over $K$ will be a subgroup of the Galois group of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.  So my comment was aimed at computing the Galois group over the field $\mathbf{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.  Hensel's lemma is used in passing from information over $\mathbf{F}_p$ to information over $\mathbf{Q}_p$.  For detailed proofs in a similar situation, see for instance "Double transitivity of Galois groups of trinomials" by Cohen/Movahhedi/Salinier, Acta Arithmetica 82 (1997), #1, 1-15.

Comment: Here is a cheap answer to your edited question. Under Artin's conjecture on primitive roots, you can prove there are infinitely many suitable $n$ for each $b\neq a\pm 1$, using the mod $p$ method from my second comment: pick $p\mid b-a$, under Artin's conjecture there are infinitely many primes $n$ such that $p$ is a primitive root modulo $n$, and for those $n$, $f$ is irreducible mod $p$.